# Should I create a new instance of Java SwingWorker each time I want to invoke doInBackground()?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My extended SwingWorker class performs a potentially reoccurring background task which requires GUI originating input variables.

I see 2 coding options:

1. To start a new instance of the class each time I use it and pass
   the variables to the constructor. I presume I should make sure there
   are not to many instances. If so how? multiton or some other method?
2. Update the variables and call execute again? If so how do I make
   sure i'm not interrupting?

Is one of these options the way to go or is there a better way?

Comment: what is this question rellated with multithreading, maybe could be important for potential answers

Comment: SwingWorker is not re-entrant, that is, you can't execute it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plase use option 1.

Immutable objects are normally easier to work with. For example, you prevent the problem that the variables are updated while the worker is still working, and you have to think less about memory visibility.

Object instantiation is quite cheap in Java, so this won't be a performance problem and you can create a new instance every time to need one.

Comment: Thanks I will approve in 5 mins when I'm allowed. How can I measure this cheapness?

Answer (score 5):

SwingWorker is non-entrant, meaning you can not execute it again, much in the same way Threads are.

From the JavaDocs

> SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a
>   SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the
>   doInBackground method twice.